# Where did Camus call Sartre's theory of commitment an illusion?

Tags: french-language, albert-camus, jean-paul-sartre

Albert Camus "is routinely categorized as an existentialist, a term he rejected on several occasions" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Camus#Existentialism)). His critique of existentialistm focused mostly on [Sartre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Paul_Sartre). Alain Vircondelet's biography *Albert Camus, fils d'Alger* (2010) mentions (on page 307) that

> Il lui apparaît de plus en plus que la fameuse théorie de l'engagement dont se gargarise Sartre est une illusion, (…)

Translation:

> The much talked-about theory of commitment that Sartre revels in increasingly seemed an illusion to him, (…)

Is this based on an article or essay by Camus or a different type of source?